# check if CMake module exists

Tags: cmake

I would like to write a CMake script that searches for a particular library; first using CMake's Find_PACKAGE(), and if that fails, I'll do something else. I started off with

```
FIND_PACKAGE(BLAS)
IF (BLAS_FOUND)
  # do stuff
ELSE()
  # do other stuff
ENDIF()
```

This works well if `FindBLAS.cmake` is available on the system (which it normally is, at least in the last couple of CMake releases). If looking for something more spurious, I'd first like to check if CMake has a module for it already, i.e., do something like

```
SET(Spurious_FOUND FALSE)
IF (HAS_MODULE_Spurious)
  FIND_PACKAGE(Spurious)
ENDIF()
IF (Spurious_FOUND)
  # do stuff
ELSE()
  # do other stuff
ENDIF()
```

How can determine if `HAS_MODULE_*`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this function:

```
function(CheckHasModule Module)
  find_package(${Module} QUIET)
  if(NOT DEFINED ${Module}_DIR)
    set(HAS_MODULE_${Module} TRUE PARENT_SCOPE)
  elseif(${Module}_DIR)
    set(HAS_MODULE_${Module} TRUE PARENT_SCOPE)
  else()
    set(HAS_MODULE_${Module} FALSE PARENT_SCOPE)
  endif()
endfunction()
```

This makes use of the fact that if a package configuration file isn't found for `VAR`, then a cache variable `VAR_DIR` is set to `VAR_DIR-NOTFOUND`.  So if the package configuration file is found, either this variable isn't defined, or it's set to a valid path (regardless of whether the `find_package` finds the requested package).

So, if you do

```
CheckHasModule(Spurious)
CheckHasModule(Threads)
message("\${HAS_MODULE_Spurious} - ${HAS_MODULE_Spurious}")
message("\${HAS_MODULE_Threads} - ${HAS_MODULE_Threads}")
```

your output should be:

> ```
> ${HAS_MODULE_Spurious} - FALSE
> ${HAS_MODULE_Threads} - TRUE
> ```